# Git: can't push changes after changing push URL in Visual Studio

Tags: git, version-control

So, I have a project in Visual Studio connected to Git source control (I have a repo on GitLab). Now, I want to create another project on GitLab and push my existing project there.

I have created a new empty project in GitLab, and tried to simply change the push URL in Visual Studio to the URL of the new project (Settings - Repository Settings - Edit push URL) and then push my changes, again through VS. However, this didn't work, I got the infamous

> refs/heads/master, pre-receive hook declined

This seemed like a simple way to do this, but now I'm guessing I need another method.

**Note**: the master branch is not protected.

Comment: did you try 'rm -rf .git' and then push it to the new repo? maybe clearing the existing git settings will help? unless you still need the first one for some reason

Comment: Is master a protected branch?

Comment: @aquaballin If possible, I'd like to keep the existing repo.

Comment: @ElpieKay It's not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying several other methods (and failing), I have discovered the problem: I couldn't push because, for some morbid reason, I was not a member of the project I have created on GitLab...

Comment: Since your problem has been solved, you can mark the answer.